# Is there a way to completely remove an HTML element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to remove/delete an HTML element from the markup directly using Javascript/jQuery/Ajax instead of using CSS `display: none`?

Comment: Just being a bit pedantic, but you're not exactly removing it from the markup - you're removing it from the Document Object Model. Markup is just the text transmitted over the wire.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes

**JavaScript**

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parentElementID');
var child = document.getElementById('childElementID');
parent.removeChild(child);
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#parentElementID').remove('#childElementID');
```

Comment: or even easier `$('#childElementId').remove()`

Comment: Agree, wanted to be more descriptive. Always suggest refactoring as much as possible.

Comment: or with "vanilla" js and without the need to "know" the parent element `child.parentNode.removeChild(child)`

Comment: I know this is from a while back and now there is a new .remove() for Vanilla JS that does not work on IE, so the remove .removeChild() is the best cross browser.  And I know there is a campaign the shite on jQuery lately for not being good enough or a hindrance, but jQuery just makes it easy.  Plan and simple.

Answer (score 7):

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, so the answers are somewhat dated.  It used to be that to remove an element, you got the parent node, the element, and use `removeChild()`, as other suggested:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

While this is still perfectly acceptable, you can now remove the node directly:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').remove();
```

```js
document.getElementById('remove-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('container').remove();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#bada55;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="remove-button">Remove</button>
```

Comment: I know this is from a while back and now there is a new .remove() for Vanilla JS and I agree with this answer and up-voted it, and that does not work on IE, so the .removeChild() is the best cross browser if you are still supporting IE for one reason or another. And I know there is a campaign the shite on jQuery lately for not being good enough or a hindrance, but jQuery just makes it easy for cross browser support.  Thanks for updating the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could use the [jQuery remove() API](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 2):

native javascript:

```
    var toremove = document.getElementById('hd');
    toremove.parentNode.removeChild(toremove);
```

Or in jquery just use

```
$('#toremove').remove();
```